# C - Is there a way to terminate string input with a key other than 'Enter'?

Tags: c, string, fgets, keycode

I'm working on an assignment scheduler for my school, the code below is a segment of a module for inputting data for a new assignment and subsequently writing that data to file. Since the assignment description may be a lengthy paragraph, I decided to allow the user to move to a new line upon pressing the Enter key for ease of input. The code I have so far works as desired.
The description is a single string however which is usually terminated with the enter key. Is it possible to terminate the string with another key? For example the Escape Key? If so, how do I go about doing this?

I was thinking of using the escape 'Esc' key to terminate string entry but I'm not sure which code or escape sequence with which to represent the key.

```
typedef struct {
    char title[60];
    Time duration;
    Date deadline;
    char descrptn[10000];
} Project;

void setStudioProject() {
    Project newProj;
    FILE *fpProj;

    system("cls");
    printf("-----PROJECT SETUP-----\n\n\n");
    //Prompt for project information
    printf("Title: ");
    fgets(newProj.title, 60, stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\nDescription: \n");
    printf("(No more than 1000 words)\n");

    //loop of concern
    while (fgets(newProj.descrptn, 10000, stdin)) {
        if (getchar() == '\r') { //Whenever the user presses the enter key
            printf("\n"); //...move to a new line
        }
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    //...
}
```

I expect the string to be read upon pressing the escape key so that execution can continue.

Comment: As Rafael points out in his answer, the terminal is line buffered (you don't get any input on stdin until the user hits enter.  One way around this is to use a double-enter (blank line) as your input termination.  So, if your program reads a line that's either zero length or just a newline by itself, you're done with input.  Then you don't have to mess with the tty settings at all...

Comment: Are you using cygwin or msys2?

Comment: Using Escape to validate input is not a good idea: unix terminals send escape sequences for special keys, starting with the escape byte (0x1B).

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` has undefined behavior. You can flush the pending input line with `{ int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') continue; }`

Comment: @chqrlie: [Here is a definition of the behavior of `fflush(stdin)`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: yes, we know Microsoft propagates its own reading of the C language. Using `fflush(stdin);` is an incorrect approach, it is not portable and may have undesirable side-effects on other platforms.

Comment: @chqrlie: Who is “we”? Do you know whether the OP knows? The statement that `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior is false, and you should not tell people false statements. A correct statement is “The behavior of `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by the C standard.” Then OP can decide for themselves whether they want to write portable code or not. They seem to be targeting Windows specifically, judging by their use of `cls`. So using Microsoft definitions may be fine by them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: OK, you have a point. I shall amend my comment.

Comment: The C Standard describes `fflush(stdin);` as having undefined behavior, however Microsoft encourages the use of this non portable call and defines what it does here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=vs-2019 . There is even an example with an explicit warning: `// fflush on input stream is an extension to the C standard`. I recommend that you instead flush the pending input line portably with `{ int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') continue; }`

Comment: @EricPostpischil: the Microsoft documentation is inconsistent: it says *If the stream was opened in read mode, or if the stream has no buffer, the call to `fflush` has no effect*, which is fine, but it goes on with a misleading example with an explicit comment `// You must flush the input buffer before using gets.` `// fflush on input stream is an extension to the C standard` ` fflush( stdin );` Either `fflush(stdin);` does nothing and the subsequent `gets_s` will read the pending newline, or it does what is implied and the documentation is **false**.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: *we* referred to you and I, and probably some other regular contributors. I do not know what the OP knows or does not know. I merely point to effective solutions. I was wrong in this particular instance because there is no pending input from a previous call to `scanf()`, unlike the example in the Microsoft  documentation. The call `fflush(stdin);` should just be removed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: OK, the net effect of `fflush(stdin);` after `scanf()` is the pending newline is discarded because it was pushed back into `stdin` by `scanf` or `scanf_s()` with `ungetc()`. The documentation should be reworded with the sentences transposed: *A call to fflush negates the effect of any prior call to ungetc for the stream*. followed by *If the stream was opened in read mode, or if the stream has no buffer, the call to fflush has no other effect, and any buffer is retained.* Note however that if the user typed a space before the newline, the *flushing* would be incomplete.

Comment: @little_birdie How do you suggest I implement this?

Comment: @DarynBrown I couldn't post it as a comment so I posted it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comment, I suggested to the questioner that his problem could possibly be better resolved by using a double newline (blank line) to indicate end-of-input instead of ESC.

He has asked for an implementation, so here's an implementation of that.  The `fgets_until_blankline` function will read multiple lines, returning when Enter is pressed twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *fgets_until_blankline(char *var, int varsize, FILE *file) {

    int inlen = 0;
    char *rc;

    var[0] = 0;
    while(rc = fgets(var+inlen, varsize-inlen, file)) {
        if(var[inlen] == '\n') {
            var[inlen] = 0;
            break;
        }
        inlen = strlen(var);
    }
    return rc;
}

int main() {

    char var[10000];

    fgets_until_blankline(var, sizeof(var), stdin);
    printf("%s", var);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Input is line-buffered by default. You can use [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) (which doesn't do this) or manually disable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
...
//ensure stdin is a terminal before modifying
if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    struct termios t;
    tcgetattr(STDOUT_FILENO, &t);//get current params

    int linebufd = ((t.c_lflag & ICANON) > 0);//check if line-buffered
    if (linebufd) {
        t.c_lflag ^= ICANON;//disable canonical line-buffering
        tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t);//update attributes and enable immediate feedback
    }
}
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 1);//make stdin stream unbuffered
```

Read more about:

- [Terminal Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Terminal-Modes.html#Terminal-Modes)
- [Stream Buffering](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Stream-Buffering)

Comment: `system("cls");` suggests that OP is using Windows, so Posix interfaces might not be available. Ought to at least be mentioned, I think. No OS tag => portable solution.